# After updating RecyclerView to sdk 25.1.1 , import statement cannot be resolved - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Just right before the update everything was working well,
after the update to the sdk version 25.1.1.

I did clean, rebuild, invalidate and restart many times.. still not fixed.

**The new version is :**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
```

**The version that was working for me:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
```

So what are the changes ? why the import statements are not resolved in the new version ?

[image: recyclerView]

Comment: try by restarting android studio with `inavalidate caches and restart` option

Comment: @UttamPanchasara Thank you for the comment. But I have tried this, i wrote it upside

Comment: Make sure sdk is updated as well

Comment: first remove imports and then try to reimport it